# Storing a Xml value as variable

Tags: php, sql

I have an xml which is something like

```
<Row>
  <RowType>Header</RowType>
  <Cells>
    <Cell />
    <Cell>
      <Value>31 Jan 11</Value>
    </Cell>
  </Cells>
</Row>
<Row>
  <RowType>Section</RowType>
  <Title>Salary</Title>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <RowType>Row</RowType>
      <Cells>
        <Cell>
          <Value>Total</Value>
```

and keeps going on

I need to get the date value  31 Jan 11 as a variable so that I could use it later for my sql insert query.

Could somebody help me on how to get the date value from the xml into a variable.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is how to convert the literal string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only need to retrieve this value of the xml file:

```
$Row = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr_file);
echo $Row->Cells[0]->Cell[1]->value;
```

Else I suggest you to check http://www.php.net/manual/fr/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to retrieve this value of the file:

```
$Row = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr_file);
echo $Row->Cells[0]->Cell[1]->value;
```